# Need Help to convert a grammar into Chomsky Form

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

I have to convert the following grammar into Chomsky Form 
$$( \Sigma=\{a,b,c,+\}, \Sigma_Q=\{S,V\},I=S)$$ 
$$S -> S+S|V$$
$$V -> a|b|c$$

My idea is the following:
$$S_0 \rightarrow S$$
$$S \rightarrow ST|V$$
$$T \rightarrow +S$$
$$V \rightarrow A|B|C$$
$$A \rightarrow a$$
$$B \rightarrow b$$
$$C \rightarrow c$$

Could you tell me if this is right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a grammar in Chomsky normal form there can only be two types of productions: $A\to BC$ and $A\to a$ where $A,B,C$ are nonterminals (variables, $\Sigma_Q$ in your notation) and $a$ is terminal ($\Sigma$ in your notation).

In particular, "chain productions" which are of the form $A\to B$ are not allowed. You have several of them. In particular, the original productions $V\to a\mid b\mid c$ were OK, while the new $V\to A\mid B\mid C$  isn't.

You have also introduced a special start symbol $S_0$. In the definition of Chomsky as I know it that s not necessary. Also note your production $T\to +S$ is of "mixed type" (it has both a terminal and a nonterminal) and is illegal.

Comment: Can I let the original productions $ V \rightarrow a|b|c$ as they are?
So is the Chomsky Form the following?
$$ S \rightarrow ST$$
$$ T \rightarrow PV$$
$$ P \rightarrow +$$
$$ V \rightarrow a|b|c$$

Comment: Close. Your productions cannot get rid of $S$. But $S\to a|b|c$ seems to fix that?

Comment: Do you mean that I have to replace V with S? 
$$ S \rightarrow ST$$
$$ T \rightarrow PS$$
$$ P \rightarrow +$$
$$ S \rightarrow a|b|c$$

Comment: Yes. (Even better than what I had in mind it seems). Your first three productions $S\to ST$, $T\to PS$, $P\to +$ can be "summarized" as $S\Rightarrow ST \Rightarrow SPS\Rightarrow S+S$ which exactly covers the main production of the original grammar.

Comment: Ok!!! Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: I have also an other question. I am asked to analyze the expression a+b+c based on the Chomsky Form. How can I do it?

Comment: Build a tree that fits a derivation for a+b+c in your grammar.

Comment: I tried to build a tree and posted it as an answer.

Comment: Is building a tree the only way to analyze an expression based on the Chomsky form?